# Putty: highlighting copying

Tags: linux, terminal, putty, ubuntu-14.04

I currently use Putty at my work, and I am always fascinated by how useful the highlight copying tool is. Is there some way I can get this same feature on my System 76 laptop when I am in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux – on the X11 graphics system – most programs *already* copy selected text. (It is actually what PuTTY emulates.)

However, they copy it to a different buffer. Explicit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will copy to the "CLIPBOARD" buffer, but simply selecting text puts it in the "PRIMARY" buffer. (These buffers are usually called [selections](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html).)

To paste from the "PRIMARY" buffer, middle-click the text area or press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd>.

(The keyboard shortcut won't work in some programs like Firefox, though; those programs always paste from the "CLIPBOARD" buffer.)

There also exist programs (clipboard managers) that automatically synchronize both buffers: [Diodon](https://launchpad.net/diodon), [Parcellite](http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/), or [autocutsel](http://www.nongnu.org/autocutsel/) (version 0.10 only – older versions have serious problems with Unicode).

Comment: I will look into what Diodonor or Parcellite has to offer. By instinct, I was working on the terminal at my home PC and highlighted the text, but it didn't copy. Thanks for the info!